# How to config database(MYSQL) or other type sources as Spring Cloud data flow's source?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm now learning using Spring Cloud data flow.But there is only 'http' type Source as a Stream's source in official preference.I wonder how to config other type sources like Database(Mysql),JMS,MongoDB etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, there are plenty of examples and an entire app starters project full of sources, processors and sinks. We put a lot of effort writing documentation, don't be lazy and come to stack overflow asking for help without even trying.

Comment: Sorry, but i've read through the document, there does is no example to config some midware as source. Could you guide me where are they? thanks